# Pass variable to new window

Tags: javascript

I have a page which have few images. checking images will add to score. it works fine with below code and score is displayed on page. Now i want a button "My score" to open a new window and display score there. Currently it gives a blank page.
Please provide code for result.html and if my current code need some changes.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
        <title></title>
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js" ></script>

 <!--*****************************************************script to count checked items Actor/Actress begin**************************************-->
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
    var actor=0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#perk1').html(actor);

        $("#img100").click(function() {
            if($('#img100').is(':checked'))
                actor=actor+1;
            else if(actor>0)
                actor=actor-1;
            $('#perk1').html(actor);
        });

        $("#img95").click(function() {
            if($('#img95').is(':checked'))
                actor=actor+1;
            else if(actor>0)
                actor=actor-1;
            $('#perk1').html(actor);
        });

    });


});//]]>  

</script>
 <!--******************************script to count checked items actor ends***************************************************************-->  
<!--******************************script to save count actor begins***************************************************************--> 
<script>
function myFunction()
{
window.open("result.html","","width=700,height=150,top=300,left=300");
}
</script>
 <!--******************************script to save count actor ends***************************************************************-->
     </head>

<!--************************************************************************body begins*************************************************************-->
  <body Body Params>
<!--*******************value of actor checked clicked here begins***************************************************-->
movies you have watched: <span id="perk1"></span></br>




<!--*******************value of actor checked clicked here ends***************************************************-->
<!--**********************************************Code to share result begins*************************************************************-->
<button onclick="myFunction()">My score</button>



<!--**********************************************Code to share result begins*************************************************************-->
</br>
Please check the movies you have watched
<!--********************************************actor movies begin************************************************************************-->
<div class="imgs">

<div class="thumb">
<label for="img100"><img src="priyanka_chopra\gunday.jpg" height="200" width="275"/></label>
<input type="checkbox" class="chk " id="img100" name="img100" value="0" />
<label for="img95"><img src="priyanka_chopra\krrish3.jpg" height="200" width="275"/></label>
<input type="checkbox" class="chk " id="img95" name="img95" value="0" />

</div>
</div>
<!--********************************************actor movies end************************************************************************-->
  </div>
<!--******************************************actor code ends***************************************************************************-->


</body>

<!--************************************************************************body ends*************************************************************-->



</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:**

You also pass your variable as URL :

Like :

**In Main Page :**

```
window.open("result.html?score="+actor,"","width=700,height=150,top=300,left=300");
```

And get Score using :

**In Result.html**

```
function geturlvar() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,             function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
   });
   return vars;
 }
```

Use to get URL Variable :

```
 var score = geturlvar()['score'];
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/pEVZe/)

May this helps you..

Comment: i have not used var score in my original code. variable name is actor.

Comment: Also, i cound not understand that which code is for main.html and which is for result.html

Comment: now nothing happen on clicking "my score" ie result.html is not opening. :(

Comment: As i see your code please make your `actor` a global variable, or pass it to the `myFunction(actor)`

Comment: Checkout my example attached,with my answer ! After make `actor` as global...@user3388005

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function geturlvar() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]

+)=([^&]*)/gi,             function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
   });
   return vars;
 }
</script>

</head>

<body>
hi

<script>
var score = geturlvar()['score'];
document.write(score);
</script>

</body>


</html>

Comment: Check your URL its have your current score or not?

Comment: Please remove another `myFunction()' you defined two same functions in your `Main html`

Answer (score 0):

You can store score variable in hidden fields and get the hidden fields value in new page or window.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it via a query string.

```
<button id="submitButton">My score</button>

$(function () {
var actor = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#perk1').html(actor);

    $("#img100").click(function () {
        if ($('#img100').is(':checked')) actor = actor + 1;
        else if (actor > 0) actor = actor - 1;
        $('#perk1').html(actor);
    });

    $("#img95").click(function () {
        if ($('#img95').is(':checked')) actor = actor + 1;
        else if (actor > 0) actor = actor - 1;
        $('#perk1').html(actor);
    });

    $("#submitButton").on("click", function () {
        alert(actor);
        var url = "result.html?val=" + actor;
        window.open(url, "", "width=700,height=150,top=300,left=300");
    });

});
}); //]]>
```

Then on the results.html page, you would grab the value from the query string similar to what is shown here; https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/173949

Comment: This gives text "undefined" in result.html

Comment: this gives message "undefined" in result.html. what code should i used in result.html?

Comment: I am learning js and your code works for alert box. please help me with code for result.html, i am not able to understand the link you added.